# Download files collection in UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, download, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to find the best approach how to download from internet collection of files. At this moment I've array of urls to files. Based on this I want to download all files one by one and show process progress on UIProgressView.

General download and store single file isn't problem for me, but I try to find how should I iterate urls connection to download all files.

Do you have any advices?

Comment: Have you looked at `NSOperationQueue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NSOperationQueue` or `ASINetworkQueue` which is a lot easier.

Here is how to use `ASINetworkQueue` : [ASI Homepage](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)